# Exact definition of WRN-d-k (Wide ResNet)

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, terminology, papers, residual-networks

I am a little confused about the WRN-d-k notation from [Wide Residual Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07146). To quote the paper,

> In the rest of the paper we use the following notation: WRN-n-k denotes
> a residual network that has a total number of convolutional layers n and a widening factor k (for example, network with 40 layers and k = 2 times wider than original would be denoted as WRN-40-2).

I need to implement WRN-28-10 as a baseline since it's one of the best-performing models in [RobustBench](https://robustbench.github.io/). According to the definition, I need to take an "original" ResNet-28 and widen its layers by a factor of 10. However, there are only 5 variants of ResNet defined in the [ResNet paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385): ResNet-[18,34,50,101,152].

How exactly are ResNet-28 and WRN-28-10 defined?

Answer (score 1):

I also found the WRN-$n$-$k$ notation confusing, but I think I can explain it:

- $n$ is the *total* number of convolutions in the model.  So to understand the architecture associated with each $n$, we have to carefully account for every convolution:

  - Each model starts with a 3x3 convolution (`conv1` in Table 1)
  - There are 3 groups of residual blocks, each the same size.
  - Each residual block has 2 convolutions, assuming we're talking about the $B(3,3)$ blocks that were found to work the best.
  - Each group has skip connection, which adds another 1x1 convolution.

  Putting this all together, we can calculate $n$ as a function of the number of residual blocks in each group, which I'll denote $b$:

  $$
    n = 1 + 3 (2b + 1)
    $$
  $$
    b = \frac{\frac{n - 1}{3} - 1}{2}
    $$

  Here are the actual number of residual blocks per group for each of the architectures discussed in the paper:

  - WRN-40-$k$: 6
  - WRN-28-$k$: 4
  - WRN-22-$k$: 3
  - WRN-16-$k$: 2
- $k$ is the factor by which the number of input channels to each residual block is multiplied.  I found this pretty self-explanatory, so I don't really know what else to say about it, but let me know in the comments if there's anything unclear.